# how to get time & data from a database that has been input ?? in PHP

Tags: php

Now I'm doing an internship in a local company. The company gave me a task; I have to be able to make a Telegram bot, but before that, I don't know how to get time & data that has been input.

I'm using Sublime Text for code and MySQL.

```php
$start = strtotime('2019-07-26 00:00:00');

$end = strtotime('2019-07-26 03:00:00');

$time = strtotime($r_smr['TO_CHAR']);

$time = substr($r_smr['TO_CHAR'], 11);

echo $time;

if ($time >= $start && $time <= $end) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "not ok";
}
```

I expect the output is the time & date that already input, but the result isn't what I expected.

Comment: You have an error in your code: `$time= strtotime($r_smr['TO_CHAR']);

$time= substr($r_smr['TO_CHAR'], 11);` you assign a different values to same var.

Comment: What is the result? What is expected? Provide `$r_smr['TO_CHAR']`.

Comment: You are comparing a timestamp number `1564368726` to string `03:00:00`! what are you expecting ?

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, 
hard to explain what i expecting because im beginner in programing, so i've got database from the company, there's table that recorded time&date, 
in example, 
1. SMR1 (recorded at 2019-07-27 2.34am)
2.SMR 2 (recorded at 2019-07-27 2.44am)

how to get data from 00.00-02.00am also the date too ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
    $start = strtotime('2019-07-26 00:00:00');

    $end = strtotime('2019-07-26 03:00:00');

    $time= strtotime('2019-07-26 02:00:00'); //used test datetime

    //$time= substr($r_smr['TO_CHAR'], 11);

    echo $time; //echo timestamp 1564124400

    if($time >= $start && $time <= $end) {

    echo "ok"; //echo ok

    } else {

      echo "not ok";

    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hi thanks for the help, it is really useful actually, but the result that i wish for is, in example i have data from 00.00-02.00 am

how to get data from that range of time ??
thank you

Comment: @Arby Sixteen you can format date like this: `echo date('H:i', $start) . " - " . date('H:i', $time);`, or read php `date()` docs: (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)